# Why I get error TypeError: Failed to fetch when using Walmart API?

Tags: walmart-api

Using Walmart Sandbox, when I submit an API request, I get below error

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

However, the later section show's Status 200, so I'm not sure if the response is correct or not. I have specified all required header.

[image]

Comment: The later section is just documentation on what the different error codes mean. I assume the error you see is a 500 error. I would try the credentials again to make sure you are using the correct sandbox keys and other option would be to use a rest client like postman and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for hint. It's very misleading.